# Pass multidimensional array to function accepting char*[]

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I do this? I get a segmentation fault.

```
void pass_array(char* arr[])
{
    cout << arr[0] << " " << arr[1] << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    #define NUM_ELEMENTS 10
    #define CHAR_LEN 32
    char arr[NUM_ELEMENTS][CHAR_LEN];
    cin >> arr[0];
    cin >> arr[1];
    cout << arr[0] << " " << arr[1] << "\n";
    pass_array((char**) arr);
}
```

I want to do this without dynamic memory. Is it possible?

I know how many elements there are in arr, but the function signature must not change.

Comment: Have you considered using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of naked arrays?

Comment: What happens when you compile and run this code?

Comment: @Code Segmentation fault.

Comment: On the highest warning level for your compiler, do you get any warnings?

Comment: What inputs are you giving?

Comment: When I tried compiling, I get an error from Visual Studio of "error C2664: 'pass_array' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [10][32]' to 'char *[]'"

Comment: @Richard no warnings, I forgot to add `(char**)` to the question

Comment: @Rajesh "hello world"

Comment: @Captain I can't use library functions

Comment: Please do not use a C style cast with C++ especially to force something that would give you a warning.

Comment: Whoever taught you to use a cast like that should be punched in the throat.

Comment: @user4081530 A 2 dimensional array is not a char**.  The only way you could have gotten that code to compile is to cast `arr` to a `char**` and then suffer the consequences when you attempted to run the program

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Arrays and pointers are different. The line `char arr[NUM_ELEMENTS][CHAR_LEN];` defines a contiguous bloc of characters; however the function is expecting a list of pointers. There are no pointers in `arr`.

You should get compiler errors when compiling this code. Using a cast to suppress the errors is telling the compiler "Ssh, I know what I'm doing". However you don't know what you are doing.

To do this without changing the function signature you will have to build a table of pointers, e.g.:

```
char *ptrs[NUM_ELEMENTS];

for (size_t i = 0; i != NUM_ELEMENTS; ++i)
    ptrs[i] = arr[i];

pass_array(ptrs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do something like the following source.

```
void pass_array(char* arr[])
{
    std::cout << arr[0] << " " << arr[1] << "\n";
}

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    #define NUM_ELEMENTS 10
    #define CHAR_LEN 32
    char arr[NUM_ELEMENTS][CHAR_LEN];
    char *arr2[NUM_ELEMENTS];

    std::cin >> arr[0]; std::cin.ignore();    // read the first string, discarding CR
    std::cin >> arr[1];                       // read the second string
    std::cout << arr[0] << " " << arr[1] << "\n";
    arr2[0] = arr[0];   // put address of first string into your argument array
    arr2[1] = arr[1];   // put address of second string into your argument array
    pass_array(arr2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want to pass a true multidimensional array, such as a matrix, or if you want to pass an array of pointers instead.

The alternate syntax for the matrix

```
char arr[number_of_rows][number_of_colums]
```

is

```
char (*arr)[number_of_columns]
```

As a simple example of a pre-initialized array of pointers:

```
char *arr[5] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use C++11 or newer versions, this should work, std::arrays are more preferable than c arrays.

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

constexpr auto numElements = 10;

auto passArray(std::array<std::string, numElements> arr) -> void
{
    std::cout << arr[0] << " " << arr[1] << std::endl;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    std::array<std::string, numElements> arr;
    std::cin >> arr[0];
    std::cin >> arr[1];
    std::cout << arr[0] << " " << arr[1] << std::endl;
    passArray(arr);
    return 0;
}
```